# Sorting a Picture to a Specific Place in the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want it to flow like this I'm doing it tons of times and dosent work.

- User pushes the photo button in the app and takes picture.
- After taking the picture users has to input detail.  sorts options comes out where user can pick 8 different default genre's, and user pushes save.
- It goes back to the Home Screen and the User can see the 8 different genre in button & when pushed pictures comes out as a coverflow(flow cover) that is saved in the app. 
   I want to make it work like the above but dosent work.

My Code is until now is:

```
@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)TakePhoto {
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
picker.delegate = self;
[picker setSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera ];
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

-(IBAction)ChooseExisting{
picker2 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
picker2.delegate = self;
[picker2 setSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[self presentViewController:picker2 animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:
(NSDictionary *) info {
image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] ;
[imageview setImage:image];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NO];
}
- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}


@end

@implementation CVCLCoverFlowLayout
-(NSInteger)count {
return [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0 ];
}
-(CGSize)collectionViewContentSize{
CGSize size = self.collectionView.bounds.size;
size.width  = self.count * self.cellInterval;
return size;
}
```

Comment: What about it doesn't work? What does it do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving the image you clicked in the delegate function .and when you want to use the saved image then you need to write down the code for same .:

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:
(NSDictionary *) info {

image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] ;

[imageview setImage:image];

***/*** save the image to local storage of your application */*

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NO];

}
You can check the code for same over :
http://dcraziee.wordpress.com/2013/05/20/how-to-save-and-get-image-from-cache-directory/

Please share the blog if you like it.